# Баг со змейкой на Python + tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Здравствуйте.
Написал тривиальную змейку на Python, вроде все ок, кроме такого бага:

Когда "голова" змеи кушает первое яблоко, добавляеться новый сегмент, но его координаты соответствуют координатам "головы", в итоге я получаю, что есть два сегмента с одними и теме же координатами. При добавлении следующих сегментов все ок, не могу понять в чем проблема.

Прикрепляю ниже полный код.

```
from tkinter import *
import random,shelve
# import shelve for saving highscore

class Game:
    # BASIC VARIABLES
    width = 700
    height = 500
    apple_size = 20
    field_color = 'black'
    score_1 = 0
    highscore = shelve.open('highscore')['highscore']
    segments = []

    # VARIABLES  AND FUNCTIONS FOR CHANGING DIRECTION
    move_left = -apple_size, 0
    move_right = apple_size, 0
    move_top = 0, -apple_size
    move_down = 0, apple_size
    direction = move_right

    def __init__(self):
        #PLAY
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Snake')
        self.field = Canvas(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=self.field_color)
        self.field.pack()
        self.field.focus_set()
        self.score = Label(self.root, text='Your score: {}. Best score: {}'.format(self.score_1, self.highscore))
        self.score.pack(side='bottom', anchor='w')

    def change_top(self):
        self.direction = self.move_top

    def change_down(self):
        self.direction = self.move_down

    def change_left(self):
        self.direction = self.move_left

    def change_right(self):
        self.direction = self.move_right

    def create_segment(self):
        b =  self.field.coords(self.segments[0])[:]
        if self.direction == self.move_right:
            for x in (0, 2):
                b[x]-=20
        elif self.direction == self.move_down:
            for x in(1,3):
                b[x]-=20
        elif self.direction == self.move_top:
            for x in(1,3):
                b[x]+=20
        else:
            for x in (0, 2):
                b[x]+=20
        new_segment=self.field.create_rectangle(*b, fill='white')
        self.segments.insert(0,new_segment)

    def game_over(self):
        if self.score_1 > self.highscore:
            shelve.open('highscore')['highscore'] = self.score_1
        self.field.create_text(self.width / 2, self.height / 2, text="GAME OVER!", font="Helvetica 20", fill="white")
        self.field.after(1500, lambda: self.root.quit())

    def create_apple(self):
        self.posx = random.randint(1,self.width/self.apple_size-1)*self.apple_size
        self.posy = random.randint(1,self.height/self.apple_size-1)*self.apple_size
        for x in range(len(self.segments)):
            if [self.posx,self.posy,self.posx+self.apple_size,self.posy+self.apple_size] ==\
                self.field.coords(self.segments[x]):
                self.create_apple()
        self.apple = self.field.create_rectangle(self.posx,self.posy,self.posx+self.apple_size,self.posy+self.apple_size,fill = 'red')

    def create_snake(self):
        self.snake = self.field.create_rectangle(20,20,40,40,fill = 'blue')
        self.segments.append(self.snake)
        def start(): #MOVING
            for x in range(len(self.segments)):
                self.a = self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1])
                print(len(self.segments))
                self.a[0]+=self.direction[0]
                self.a[1]+=self.direction[1]
                self.a[2]=self.a[0]+self.apple_size
                self.a[3]=self.a[1]+self.apple_size
                if x == 0:
                    self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1], self.a )
                else:
                    self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1],*self.field.coords(self.segments[x]))
            if self.field.coords(self.segments[-1]) == self.field.coords(self.apple): # IF SNAKE'S EATEN AN APPLE
                self.score_1+=1
                self.score.config(text = 'Your score: {}. Best score: {}'.format(self.score_1,self.highscore))
                self.field.delete(self.apple)
                self.create_apple()
                self.create_segment()
            if self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[0] == 0 or self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[0] == self.width or\
            self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[1] == self.height or self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[1] == 0: # IF SNAKE'S RUN INTO WALL
                self.game_over()
            for x in range(2, len(self.segments)): # SELF-EATING
                if self.field.coords(self.segments[0]) == self.field.coords(self.segments[x]):
                    self.game_over()
            self.field.after(200,start)
        return  start()

    def lets_play(self): #START
        self.create_apple()
        self.create_snake()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.field.bind('<Up>', lambda x: game.change_top())
    game.field.bind('<Down>', lambda x: game.change_down())
    game.field.bind('<Left>', lambda x: game.change_left())
    game.field.bind('<Right>', lambda x: game.change_right())
    game.lets_play()
```

Comment: По поводу стиля - у вас классический ["объект-бог"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Божественный_объект). По факту у вас обычный процедурный код, зачем-то завернутый в класс. Если уж писать в ООП-стиле - тогда нужно выделить игровые объекты (например, яблоко, змею и т.д.) в отдельные классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Баг очень тяжело проявляеться в коде, а код написан не правильно. Так что это конечно весьма дичевое решение, но что поделать:

```
import random
import shelve

from tkinter import *


class Game:
    # BASIC VARIABLES
    width = 700
    height = 500
    apple_size = 20
    field_color = 'black'
    score_1 = 0
    highscore = shelve.open('highscore').get('highscore', 0)
    segments = []

    # VARIABLES  AND FUNCTIONS FOR CHANGING DIRECTION
    MOVE_LEFT = -apple_size, 0
    MOVE_RIGHT = apple_size, 0
    MOVE_TOP = 0, -apple_size
    MOVE_DOWN = 0, apple_size

    def __init__(self):
        self.apple = None
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Snake')
        self.field = Canvas(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=self.field_color)
        self.field.pack()
        self.field.focus_set()
        self.you_score = 0
        self.label_score = Label(self.root, text='Your score: {}. Best score: {}'.format(self.you_score, self.highscore))
        self.label_score.pack(side='bottom', anchor='w')
        self.change_right()

    def update_label(self):
        self.label_score.config(text = 'Your score: {}. Best score: {}'.format(self.you_score, self.highscore))

    def change_top(self):
        self.direction = self.MOVE_TOP

    def change_down(self):
        self.direction = self.MOVE_DOWN

    def change_left(self):
        self.direction = self.MOVE_LEFT

    def change_right(self):
        self.direction = self.MOVE_RIGHT

    def create_segment(self):
        prev_cord = self.field.coords(self.segments[0])[:]
        cord = prev_cord[:]
        if self.direction == self.MOVE_RIGHT:
            for x in (0, 2):
                cord[x] -= 20
        elif self.direction == self.MOVE_LEFT:
            for x in (0, 2):
                cord[x] += 20
        elif self.direction == self.MOVE_DOWN:
            for x in(1,3):
                cord[x] -= 20
        elif self.direction == self.MOVE_TOP:
            for x in(1,3):
                cord[x] += 20
        new_segment = self.field.create_rectangle(*cord, fill='white')
        self.segments.insert(0, new_segment)
        if len(self.segments) == 2:
            self.segments.insert(1, self.__get_new_head(prev_cord))

    def game_over(self):
        if self.you_score > self.highscore:
            shelve.open('highscore')['highscore'] = self.you_score
        self.field.create_text(self.width / 2, self.height / 2, text="GAME OVER! {label}".format(label=self.label_score.cget("text")), font="Helvetica 20", fill="white")
        self.field.after(1500, lambda: self.root.quit())

    def create_apple(self):
        self.posx = random.randint(1,self.width/self.apple_size-1)*self.apple_size
        self.posy = random.randint(1,self.height/self.apple_size-1)*self.apple_size
        for x in range(len(self.segments)):
            if [self.posx,self.posy,self.posx+self.apple_size,self.posy+self.apple_size] ==\
                self.field.coords(self.segments[x]):
                self.create_apple()
        self.apple = self.field.create_rectangle(self.posx,self.posy,self.posx+self.apple_size,self.posy+self.apple_size,fill = 'red')

    def create_snake(self):
        self.segments.append(self.__get_new_head())
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        for x, _ in enumerate(self.segments):
            self.a = self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1])
            self.a[0] += self.direction[0]
            self.a[1] += self.direction[1]
            self.a[2] = self.a[0] + self.apple_size
            self.a[3] = self.a[1] + self.apple_size
            if x == 0:
                self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1], self.a)
            else:
                self.field.coords(self.segments[x-1], *self.field.coords(self.segments[x]))
        if self.field.coords(self.segments[-1]) == self.field.coords(self.apple):
            self.you_score += 1
            self.update_label()
            self.field.delete(self.apple)
            self.create_apple()
            self.create_segment()
        if self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[0] == 0 or self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[0] == self.width or\
        self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[1] == self.height or self.field.coords(self.segments[-1])[1] == 0: # IF SNAKE'S RUN INTO WALL
            self.game_over()
        for x in range(2, len(self.segments)): # SELF-EATING
            if self.field.coords(self.segments[0]) == self.field.coords(self.segments[x]):
                self.game_over()
        self.field.after(200, self.start)

    def lets_play(self): #START
        self.create_apple()
        self.create_snake()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def __get_new_head(self, cord=(20, 20, 40, 40)):
        return self.field.create_rectangle(*cord, fill='blue')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.field.bind('<Up>', lambda x: game.change_top())
    game.field.bind('<Down>', lambda x: game.change_down())
    game.field.bind('<Left>', lambda x: game.change_left())
    game.field.bind('<Right>', lambda x: game.change_right())
    game.lets_play()
```

Comment: Спасибо, почему считаете, что код написан неправильно?

Comment: Трудно обьяснить, для студента может и хорошо. В коде нет например четкой логики, то есть когда вы увеличивете длину змеи, вы не вызываете функцию increase_shake, а делаете все в функции start. P.S. Не воспринимайте это близко к серцу, препод код должен принять, а у меня вполне вероятно просто проф-деформация после написания бизнес-кода...

Comment: Пишу не для препода, а для себя, саморазвития. Когда я увеличиваю длину змеи, я вызываю метод create_segment, разве это не то, что нужно? В общем, такой код имеет право на существование ? :)